# Completely unable to connect to Internet via Ethernet

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, ethernet, configuration-profiles

2020 13-inch MacBook Pro, OS 12.1, for some info

So the title is pretty self explanatory. I've been able to connect to WiFi just fine, but every time I connect via Ethernet, I get this notification:

> [Device Name] has a self-assigned IP address and will not be able to connect to the Internet.

I have tried every way I can find online to get around this: new ethernet cables, different adaptors, rebooting and, most recently, trashing the plist files, when I ran into the curious issue.

It looks like, when I head to the system configuration folder, the file *"com.apple.network.identification.plist"* is nowhere to be seen. Following the other steps I've been told to do everywhere have yielded no results, and with my limited computer knowledge, I'm at a total loss. Please help! I don't think I can survive on campus WiFi forever!

For starters, is the lack of this file the reason my Ethernet adaptors won't work? They worked last year on campus, in a different room. Secondly, if the loss of the file is the issue, how do I get it reinstalled?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: There are some older questions about the same issue https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=has+a+self-assigned+IP+address+and+will+not+be+able+to+connect+to+the+Internet. It might be worth checking the answers.

Comment: Current Monterey is 12.6 - perhaps a bug has been fixed in the intervening period.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Interesting... I have the same MacBook Pro model (13-inch, 2020, Four Thunderbolt 3 ports) and have been able to connect via Ethernet with all Monterey versions just fine... What is the make and model of your Ethernet adapter? Has the connection over Ethernet worked in the past? Have you had a chance to test your Ethernet cable and adapter with another computer?